# list with random value

Tags: python

I'm looking to do a list containing random numbers, then taking the biggest, smallest value and then getting the average value of the list.

```
import random
list=[None]*50
for i in range (1,50):
    list[i]=random.randint(1,100)
```

This is what I got so far

Comment: too broad for SO. Start with Google, break your  question into the 4 separate parts and search. You will get links to 4 top voted content. But remember start with the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial)

Comment: Iterate over the list making a note of the largest and smallest values you have found. Each time you find a larger or smaller value update it. The average is the sum divided by the count. Is the problem that you don't know what largest, smallest and average means? Is the problem that you don't know what a Python list is?

Comment: Please attached your code here and ask the question.

Comment: Hi there @Samuel! Welcome to the site :) Questions on [so] need to show a certain level of "research effort" - that means you'll need to show that you'e at least tried to start solving the problem yourself. Please take a few mins to refactor your post to include any attempts you have already made - without this, it just looks to the users that you are asking them to do your work/homework for you.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've provided? what does it do and what should it do? Please take the time to *describe* your question

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do for this:

```
import random
In [11]: maxint = 10000
In [12]: listlen = 100
```

Creating the list:

```
In [13]: mylist = [random.randrange(maxint) for _ in range(listlen)]
```

The questions you ask are builtins in python:

```
In [14]: max(mylist)
Out[14]: 9993

In [15]: min(mylist)
Out[15]: 10

In [16]: sum(mylist)/len(mylist)
Out[16]: 4734.37
```

Comment: You could consider writing `for _ in range(..)` to denote that you don't actually need the variable.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe : You're right, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has some errors. You first have to create an empty list with `list = []` and then create `10` random numbers (from `1` to `100`) using `for` as follows:

```
import random
list = []
for i in range (10):
    list.append(random.randint(1,100))

print list
print max(list)
print min(list)
print sum(list) / float(len(list))
```

Output:

```
[68, 59, 87, 6, 41, 67, 91, 46, 79, 28]
91
6
57.2
```

Using `float` calculating the averate will give you a more accurate result rather than using only `len`.